# Confusing notation for vector bundle connection written in terms of projection

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am confused by a passage in a paper I am reading and was hoping someone could shed some light on it. It reads as follows.

"An idempotent $p\in M_r(C^\infty(M))$ determines a vector bundle $\text{im}\,p$ over $M$, with connection
$$pdp+(1-p)d(1-p)=d+(2p-1)dp."$$

Here $M_r$ denotes the $r\times r$ matrices, and $M$ is a smooth closed manifold. What I am confused about is the interpretation of the de Rham differential here. More precisely:

1. What does $dp$ mean here? Is it $d\circ p$, or multiplication by the entrywise differential of $p$?
2. How does one prove the quoted equality?

*Comment*: I understand that the Grassmannian connection on $\text{im}\,p$ is often written as $pdp$, meaning $p\circ d\circ p$. This doesn't seem to be what the author has in mind, since if $v\in\text{im}\,p$ then $(1-p)v=0$, so the term $(1-p)d(1-p)$ is redundant. On the other hand, if one interprets $dp$ as the pointwise differential of $p$, then $d(1-p)$ is just $-dp$, and I can't see where the $d$ on the right-hand side of the quoted equality would come from.

I would appreciate it if someone could write down the computation in more detail.